# User Login System with File Delivery?

Tags: login

I'm wondering if it's possible through a plugin, or otherwise, to allow people to register on my WordPress site for an account. And then through my control panel, I can manage their accounts. Here's a little backstory of what I'm trying to accomplish.

My client runs a dance competition. They would like to be able to upload audio critiques, videos and media. And they'd like to be able to deliver that content just to specific accounts. For instance, a mother goes to the site and registers an account. She logs in and is able to get media related to her son or daughter from a control panel that my client uploaded specifically for them.

Is this within the realm of possibility in WordPress? Does a solution already exist? And if not, if anyone could suggest a workaround that would be great.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this very easily with simple using my plugin [**User Specific Content**](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/user-specific-content-plugin) which lets you display specific content per user name, user id or by user role.